# Actionscript 3, Play a specific part of an MP3 file without loading all of it?

Tags: flash, audio, actionscript, streaming, arrays

I have a project at office which is mp3 player

its almost finished but I have a problem in which I need your help

when a user start a song from any point, the whole mp3 file gets loaded then start to play from the point user selected

so now I need a solution to be able to play the mp3 from a specific time without loading the whole mp3 to be able to do that

(You know like youtube when you click in the middle of a video and it starts to play from this point)

Any help will be greatly appreciated, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Youtube videos are broadcasted by a streaming server which allows you to jump to a specific position without loading everything. This is not possible with a standard file server. You must send your mp3 onto a streaming server to do so (red5, FMS, online streaming service...), but I guess it may be overkill for your project.

Comment: Thanks for your reply,
So its not possible even with something like bytearray or anything ?